Birational change the variety to the higher model if the nonKLT locus is connected?
I was reading the paper BCHM, there is an application of BCHM results to the proof of inversion of adjunction in this paper:

Corollary 1.4.5 (Inversion of adjunction). Let $(X, \Delta)$ be a log pair and let $\nu: S \longrightarrow$ $S^{\prime}$ be the normalisation of a component $S^{\prime}$ of $\Delta$ of coefficient one.
If we define $\Theta$ by adjunction,
$$
\nu^*\left(K_X+\Delta\right)=K_S+\Theta
$$
then the log discrepancy of $K_S+\Theta$ is equal to the minimum of the log discrepancy with respect to $K_X+\Delta$ of any valuation whose centre on $X$ is of codimension at least two and intersects $S$.

In the proof (page 466, the 3rd paragraph of the proof) there is a technique that I can not figure it out:
Suppose the pair $(X,\Delta)$ is not PLT. Then by BCHM, we can extract certain set of exceptional divisors. And we get a birational projective morphism $\pi:Y\to X$ with $$K_Y+\Gamma = \pi^*(K_X+\Delta),$$ such that $Y$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial and $K_Y$ is KLT. Then by connectedness principle, we may assume nonKLT locus of  $K_Y+\Gamma$ is connected. Then the paper claim that we can free to replace $X$ by $Y$.
Here is question: How connectedness of NKLT locus is used in order to change $X$ to the higher model $Y$?

the connectedness is used to guarantee that if there exists a center intersect S, then there exists a center intersect the strict transform of S.

Thank you Professor Jiang, I will try to write down the detail of the proof.

I found the same idea from the paper "Anti-pluricanonical systems on Fano varieties" section about lifting sections from non-klt centres.
